# How do I add a script tag to one page on my WordPress website and add attributes?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I need to add this header tag to one custom built page (called membership.php) on my WordPress Website:

```
<script src="https://js.chargebee.com/v2/chargebee.js"  data-cb-site="company-name" > </script>
```

I would usually add a tag with an enqueue to the functions.php, but that would appear on every page AND the scripts I usually connect do not have attribues built into the tag.

Please could you help?

- How do I add a header tag to only 1 page?
- If the correct way is to enueue it, how do I add attributes?

Thanks in advance for any pointers or help you may be able to give.

Joe

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you create a template for that specific page and use the `is_page_template('path/file.php')` to enqueue on that template.

i.e

```
function specific_enqueue() {
    if ( is_page_template( 'sample-template.php' ) ) {
        //
    } else {
        //
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'specific_enqueue' );
```

If you want to gain more knowledge about this specific topic you can read it here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/

If you struggle to use `is_page_template` function refer to this article for help:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/238640/what-does-is-page-template-compare-against